# whmcs compatibility with phpmailer 5.2.18

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, whmcs

I'm using whmcs 4.4.2 on an old website and using gmail smtp to send invoices. today i noticed that no email is sending. so tried to manualy send an email but it just showed blank page and did nothing. I contacted my hosting provider and they said they have upgraded all phpmailer scripts on their servers, so I need to make whmcs compatible with the latest version of phpmailer.

my question is how to make my whmcs compatible to PHPMailer 5.2.18. I appreciate any help

** upgrading whmcs is not an option. I'm just going to take care of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The classes and code in WHMCS that call phpmailer are encoded. I don't expect you are going to be able to get access to them. As I see it you have two options:

1) Upgrade WHMCS. The version you are running has known security issues. 
2) Move hosts and then downgrade phpmailer back to the files shipped with the product.